# How to index data that comes from ajax response in php

Tags: php, ajax

Hi sir i have a problem related to ajax response,here is data that comes from ajax response `[200,300,400]` and i want this type of output `a=[200],b=[300]` how is it possible in ajax.please help.

Comment: What you want to do is looping an JSON array. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/g30b6ty2/)

Answer (score 1):

the array is by default binding with key starting from 0.

```
$.each(yourArray, function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

will display you array with key and value
Hope this helps..

Comment: sir this is my php code $to[0]=100;
$to[1]=200;
$to[2]=300;
 echo json_encode($to);    i am geting this data  [100,200,300]  after using your code  i am getting  0:[ ,1: 1,2:0,3:0 etc what i do